# How to keep track of password ages using samba?

Tags: windows, samba, smb

I have configured samba using authentication mode as User. Also, recently I changed samba password using `smbpasswd -r domainname -U username` this changes the password for windows domain account.

Is there any command by which we can get information about password age?

Answer (score 1):

[pdbedit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/pdbedit.8.html)
DESCRIPTION

> This tool is part of the samba(7) suite.
>
> The pdbedit program is used to manage the users accounts stored in the sam database and can only be run by root.
>
> The pdbedit tool uses the passdb modular interface and is independent
>          from the kind of users database used (currently there are smbpasswd,
>          ldap, nis+ and tdb based and more can be added without changing the
>          tool).

Command ...

```
pdbedit -v -u $USER | grep must
```

shows

```
Password must change: {date time}
```

---

```
pdbedit -L -v $USER
```

shows lots of info about a user.

---

That command needs to be run as "root".

Comment: Actually I want to get information about windows domain account password age, does this command will give me this?

Comment: No. doubt Linux can get that sort of info from Windows.

Comment: and $USER should present in windows domain account right?

Comment: Change that for nothing for all users or a username yes.

Comment: Actually I have different user in Linux and WIndows that's why asked.